# php oop connection issue. The error that it shows is briefly explained below

Tags: php, oop, object

This is the error I'm getting:

> mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, object given in E:\wamp\www\mm\classes\db_class.php on line 11

I have three files

1. config.php
2. db_class.php
3. index.php

**config.php**

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
define('HOST','localhost');
define('USER','root');
define('PASSWORD','');
define('DATABASE','mm');

class con {
    function __construct(){
        $con=mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
        // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
    }
}
```

**db_class.php**

```
<?php

    include 'config.php';

    class db {
        private $con;
        function __construct($con) {
            $this->con=$con;
        }
        public function product(){
            $con=$this->con;
            $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM attribute_id")or die (mysql_error());    
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $arr[]= $row;
            }   
            return $arr;
        }   
    }

?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

    include "classes/db_class.php";

    $con=new con();
    $products= new db($con);
    $product_data= $products->product();
    print_r($product_data);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the statement here,

```
$con=new con();
```

Here you're actually getting a reference to the current object, not the connection handler. Either create a separate property `private $con` in the `con` class and use it as your connection handler, or create your connection in `db` class itself.

## Method(1):

**config.php**

```
// your define() statements

class con {
    private $con;
    function __construct(){
        $this->con=mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
        // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
    }

    public function getConnection(){
        return $this->con;
    }

}
```

**db_class.php**

```
// your db_class.php page will be as it is
```

**index.php**

```
include "classes/db_class.php";

$con=new con();
$connection = $con->getConnection();
$products= new db($connection);
$product_data= $products->product();
print_r($product_data);
```

## Method(2):

**db_class.php**

```
// there's no need of con class
// your define() statements here

class db {
    private $con;
    function __construct() {
        $this->con=mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
        // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
    }
    public function product(){
        $result = mysqli_query($this->con,"SELECT * FROM attribute_id")or die (mysql_error());    
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $arr[]= $row;
        }   
        return $arr;
    }   
}
```

**index.php**

```
include "classes/db_class.php";

$products= new db();
$product_data= $products->product();
print_r($product_data);
```

Comment: randeep it solved the error problem but it doesn't show the array

Comment: @AbdurRehmanFarooqi Which method did you use? And what's the error now? Are you sure `attribute_id` is the correct table name?

Comment: It was product_attribute.Thanks man @RajdeepPaul ! It worked perfectly. i think i need to take a break.

Comment: @AbdurRehmanFarooqi Glad I could help. Please *accept* the answer if it resolved your issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

The confusion may come from using same name for many things...
However, the `$con` you pass to `new db($con)` is the instance of the class con created in index.php. It should be the `$con` created inside the constructor of class con...